# How to add svg end of a progress bar manipuleted by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, frontend

I am coding a porgress bar and this progress is increasing or decreasing according to the degree from javascript. It's okay if the progress bar doesn't work, but I want to add a triangle svg to the end of this bar and make it arrow shaped.

The progress bar I made looks like this:
[my ipmpementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvE0E.png)

but I want it to look like this:
[how i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV7UB.png)

The html structure of the progress bar is as follows:

```
<div class="progress-container">
     <div class="progress__fill"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the progress bar javascript code:

```
<script >
    function updateProgressBar(progressBar) {
        progressBar.querySelector(".progress__fill").style.width = VALUE;
    }
const myProgressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-container");
updateProgressBar(myProgressBar); </script>
```

As you can see, it changes according to the progress bar value variable, so I didn't know how to add the svg in the form of triangle at the end.

Comment: see the SVG ``<marker>`` documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer exactly your question, check snippet.
Now you have another way to do that with css triangle in after pseudo class

```js
let VALUE = '50%';

function updateProgressBar(progressBar) {
  progressBar.querySelector(".progress__fill").style.width = VALUE;
}
const myProgressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-container");
updateProgressBar(myProgressBar);
```

```css
.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.progress__fill {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.progress-container svg {
  float: left;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress__fill"></div>
  <svg id="svgTriangle" fill="#ff0000" viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M 0,48 V 0 l 48,24 z" />
    </svg>
</div>
```